# PHP MVC structure and dynamic URL re-writing

Tags: php

I have followed a youtube playlist to build a simple MVC framework based on PHP, here is a [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OsCTzGASImQ&list=PLfdtiltiRHWGXVHXX09fxXDi-DqInchFD) to the playlist I have followed.

and here is an image of my application structure
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQjMz.png)

I have connected the application to a MySql database, everything is working fine, but now I am trying to do friendly URLs.

Currently, my URLs look like the following:

```
mywebsite.com/home/listings/
```

this is fine as this link is for a static page, but I want the same for dynamic URLs, for example:

Current URL: `mywebsite.com/home/listings/apart?id=10`

to URL: `mywebsite.com/home/listings/apart/id/10`

I have tried a lot of methods in htaccss but the data is not pulled from the database once the URL is re-written and I get only an empty page.

current .htaccess code (the one that is located in the public folder):

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /public

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

I have tried a lot of methods and rules but non have worked.

I am not sure if the details I provided are clear enough, I am little confused as I combined a lot of tutorials together to create this app.

App.php code:

```
<?php
  class App{
    protected $controller = 'home';
    protected $method = 'index';
    protected $params = [];
    public function __construct(){
      $url = $this->parseUrl();
        if(file_exists('../app/controllers/' . $url[0] . '.php')){
          $this->controller = $url[0];
          unset($url[0]);
        }
        require_once '../app/controllers/' .$this->controller. '.php';
        $this->controller = new $this->controller;

        if(isset($url[1])){
          if(method_exists($this->controller, $url[1])){
            $this->method = $url[1];
            unset($url[1]);
          }
        }
        $this->params = $url ? array_values($url) : [];
        call_user_func_array([$this->controller, $this->method], $this->params);
    }

    public function parseUrl(){
      if(isset($_GET['url'])){
        return $url = explode('/', filter_var(rtrim($_GET['url'], '/'), FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
        echo $url;
      }
    }
  }
 ?>
```

controller.php code:

```
<?php
  class Controller{
    public function model($model){
      require_once '../app/models/' . $model . '.php';
      return new $model();
    }
    public function view($view, $data = []){
      require_once '../app/views/' . $view . '.php';
    }
  }
 ?>
```

controllers code:

```
<?php
  class home extends Controller{
    public function index(){
      $this->view('home/index');
    }
    public function listings(){
      $this->view('home/listings');
    }
    public function property(){
      $this->view('home/property');
    }
  }
 ?>
```

The project is online, I can give full access if someone interested in helping me solve this issue.

Comment: can you post the code of `core/Controller.php` Presuming that's got the bit which parses `$_GET['url']`, btw no one want to sit through a youtube series looking for your issue, please post it here.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone thank you for your interest in my issue, I just provided the youtube link to give a clear idea about the tutorial I have followed, but of course, I don't want anyone to follow up with it to solve my issue.

anyway I have included the controller code, please let me know if there is any other code that can help solve the problem.

Comment: Ok in the App code, where it returns into `$url` you should put that inside  `$this->params` like `$this->params['params']`, then you will be able to access the proceeding URL path from your controllers method. Can't tell which but it will be in the  methodName($somthing)` in your controller file. Post a controllers mmetods code if you need further help

Comment: Actually second look, I see its already being passed as `$this->params` so post the code of one of your controllers methods

Comment: Done, I have included the code

Comment: Ok say in `public function listings(){` change it to `public function listings(array $params) {` and do `print_r($params)` and your see your url parts. then just select out what you want `$params[2]` etc.

Comment: ok, it worked, I only did the following, 

`public function property($params){
      $this->view('home/property', $_GET['id'] = $params);
    }`

Answer (score 1):

## Controller methods need args. App call needs specific params.

In app.php's `call_user_func_array()` you're already trying to pass arguments to the Controller method being called. You just need the methods to have arguments.

Please be aware that you'll need *some* validation on your args, as anyone can put anything there.

The absolute simplest form of an answer I can give:

#### /app/controllers/home.php

```
public function listings($type = '', $field = null, $value = null){
    $viewParams = [];

    // build model (much of this should be in controller.php)
    // only allow known types
    if (in_array($type, ['apartment','house']) {
        $model = $this->model($type);

        // again, only certain fields (this should be handled in model.php)
        if (in_array($field, ['id','allowedField']) {

            // this is where things can get REALLY dicey. 
            // you'll need to sanitize the value, AND make sure the data-type is compatible with the field
            $modelData = $model->findAndLoadData([$field => $value]);
            $viewParams['type'] = $type;
            $viewParams[$type] = $modelData;
        }
    }

    $this->view('home/listings', $viewParams);
}
```

Keep in mind the following caveats:

- There are MANY ways to structure this, and the logic here can be in app, base controller, or the models.
- Sanitize $value, or build your models so it doesn't matter.
- You still have to find a way to use those params in the view.

Comment: I have included the App.php code, please let me know if you need any other code that can help solve the problem.

Comment: @AhmadTahhan have a look.

Comment: Thanks, but I have a lot of questions regarding your answer as this is my first PHP project that is based on MVC and OOP, 

what do you mean by building a model in the controller.php, do you mean to build the findAndLoadData method, 

Also, what do you mean by only allowed fields, do you mean fields that exist in the MySQL database.

Comment: I did the following and it worked, I don't know if this is a valid way, 

`public function property($params){
      $this->view('home/property', $_GET['id'] = $params);
    }`

Comment: @Ahmad, by "buiding a model", I mean collecting data from your db, and turning into an object in PHP. These models (M in MVC) should be clearly defined classes, and the only way the rest of your application interacts with the DB. Code to build these models should either be part of your core (in app.php), or in your base `Controller` class.

Comment: @AhmadTahhan, by "allowed fields", I mean that you should always treat data in the request (URL, querystring, form posts) as malicious. Consider what someone could do to break your application. Where this data is passed to a database, use PHP::PDO. Where this data is used to build strings for calling classes and methods, check that these strings represent valid and intended classes and methods. The easiest way to do that is to define a white-list for those strings (as in my example).

Comment: @AhmadTahhan, also please consider that there ARE vulnerabilities and methods to exploit PHP file access (like file_exists). So you should probably consider at least _some_ level of abstraction between user-input and file-names.